# C++ Template int and strings

Tags: c++, templates, types

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Tyler{
    T first, second;
    public:
        Tyler(T a, T b)
        {
            first = a;
            second = b;
        }
        int larger();
        string larger();

};

template <class T>
int Tyler<int>::larger()
{
    cout << "int larger" <<endl;
    return(first>second?first:second);
}

template <class T>
string Tyler<string>::larger()
{
    cout << "string larger" <<endl;
    if(first.compare(second) > 0)
        return(first);
    return(second);
}

int main()
{
    Tyler<int> tobj(7,77);
    Tyler<string> tstr("Seven", "test");

    cout << tobj.larger() <<endl;
    cout << tstr.larger() <<endl;

}
```

I am learning C++ (templates in particular) and trying to understand. What if I wanted to create the two functions below and the "larger" function will perform different depending on which datatype is specified in the class instantiated in main. I have only seen examples that use int and float.

Comment: Are you trying to create a function which performs operations depending upon the types given to it?

Comment: You do not need two `larger()` functions in the template class, just one: `T larger()`. Notice, that the return type is `T` which is completely fine. At the implementations: Leave out `class T` from the specializations.

Comment: @MtRoad yes I am trying to create two larger functions and each function will do something different depending on what datatype is given to it.

Comment: @Notinlist I do understand that for this particular example strings can be compared using the relational operators and thus really only one function is needed. However, lets say that I wanted to perform special tasks related to strings only...

Comment: @TylerBrown I know exactly. Check this out: http://codepad.org/HBGhd8IA

Comment: Pass parameters to constructor by const reference and use the initializer list otherwise you copy them twice. Why not `const T& Larger() const { return std::min(first, second); }` function?

Answer (score 0):

First, you appear to be trying to specialize the function, so your declarations are not right.  You should have this declaration.

```
T larger();
```

You want each `Tyler` object to have only a single `larger` function, that does different things depending on `T`.  Next, the definitions:

```
int Tyler<int>::larger()
```

Here, you're creating a template specialization.  It's a template function (well, sort of), so it does need the `template` bit atop it, but this specialization requires no template parameters, so...

```
template<>
int Tyler<int>::larger()
```

Why is that useful?  Well, because sometimes a specialization *can* have template parameters...

```
template<class T, class Allocator>
vector<T,Allocator> Tyler<  vector<T,Allocator>  >::larger()
```

Comment: How would I go about defining these functions? `int larger();` and `string larger();` the compiler complains that `'templates.cpp:16:10: error: 'std::string Tyler<T>::larger()' cannot be overloaded
templates.cpp:15:7: error: with 'int Tyler<T>::larger()'`

Comment: @TylerBrown: That's because your template definition declares `int larger();` and `string larger();` regardless of the template parameter. Change it to a single `T larger();` if you want different specialisations to return different types.